# Version error when launching hyperledger composer rest server docker

Tags: docker, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

A little background: I have a business network running on IBM cloud hyperledger starter edition. It's built with composer v0.19.14, and as far as I can tell, everything is v0.19.14 and should work with Fabric v1.1. I can deploy my BNA and view with composer playground and even launch composer-rest-server from my machine locally and everything looks good. But when I try to launch my docker composer rest server, I get a version compatibility error. I've searched everywhere and tried all the recommendations out there, but to no avail.

Here is the error when launching the docker in -it mode:

`Error: Error trying to ping. Error: Composer runtime (0.19.14) is not compatible with client (0.19.12)`

Here's my Dockerfile:

`FROM hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.14`

Here's my build script:

`docker build -t hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.14 .
source envvars_simple.txt
docker run \
    -it \
    -e COMPOSER_CARD=${COMPOSER_CARD} \
    -e COMPOSER_NAMESPACES=${COMPOSER_NAMESPACES} \
    -e COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION=${COMPOSER_AUTHENTICATION} \
    -e COMPOSER_MULTIUSER=${COMPOSER_MULTIUSER} \
    -e COMPOSER_APIKEY=${COMPOSER_APIKEY} \
    -v ~/.composer:/home/composer/.composer \
    --name rest \
    -p 3001:3000 \
    sample/sample-hyperledger-rest-server`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a dummy. So the problem was that docker run kept trying to pull an old image from docker hub called sample/sample-hyperledger-rest-server that i created, but didn't bother to update. This is a simple case of my bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is in the first line

`docker build -t hyperledger/composer-rest-server:0.19.12 .`

You are pulling down a composer-rest-server based docker image with **v0.19.12** where the remainder of your components are **0.19.14**.  Try pulling the same version of the container and it should be ok.

Comment: You know that's one of the lines i've changed to try every possible option, and 0.19.14 was one of those. I probably should have changed it back before posting here. May just do that.